# How to find basis for $\ker(L)$ and $\operatorname{ran}(L)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $V=\mathbb R^{2 \times 2}$ be the vector space of $2\times 2$ matrices and let $L\colon V\to V$ be defined by $L(X)= AX$, where $$A = \begin{bmatrix}8&-4\\2&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$
>   Find a basis for $\ker(L)$. Find a basis for $\operatorname{ran}(L)$.

The answer is supposed to be in the form of two $2\times2$ matrices for each but I'm not sure how to find the basis for a two by two matrix. I row reduced to find the basis of $\ker(L) = \begin{bmatrix}1/2\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and the basis of $\operatorname{ran}(L) = \begin{bmatrix}8\\2\end{bmatrix}$ but I'm not sure how to proceed after that.

Comment: Hint: $$\pmatrix{8 & -4 \\ 2 & -1}\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d} = \pmatrix{8a-4c & 8b -4d \\ 2a -c & 2b-d} \leftrightarrow \pmatrix{8 & 0 & -4 & 0 \\ 0 & 8 & 0 & -4 \\ 2 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & -1}\pmatrix{a \\ b \\ c \\ d}=\pmatrix{8a-4c \\ 8b-4d \\ 2a-c \\ 2b-d}$$

Comment: Thank you! I understand how to find the basis for 2x2 now

Comment: @Bye_World: whoops, misread the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS noted in the comment of Bye_World we have:
$$
L(M)=
\begin{bmatrix}
8&-4\\
2&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
4(2a-c)&4(2b-d)\\
2a-c&2b-d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so, for the kernel of $L$ we have: $L(M)=0 \Rightarrow 2a=c \;\land \; 2b=d$ , i.e. the matrices :
$$
K=
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
2a&2b
\end{bmatrix}=
a\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
2&0
\end{bmatrix}
+b\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
0&2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And, since the two matrices at RHS are linearly independent they are a basis for $Ker (L)$.

For the Rank of $L$ we can do the same notice that a matrix $R$ in the range is of  the form:
$$
R=\begin{bmatrix}
4k&4h\\
k&h
\end{bmatrix}=k
\begin{bmatrix}
4&0\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}+
h\begin{bmatrix}
0&4\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$